# json_decode php returns null on valid json

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, post

I am trying to send a json object through ajax post in javascript as follows:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'testPost.php',
                    data: {json: cond},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response) {
                        alert(response["json"]);
                    }
                });
```

cond represents the json object which is something like this(converted with JSON.stringify):

[{"field":"name","condition":"<","value":"John"}]

on testPost.php file I have the following:

```
    <?php
       $return=$_POST["json"];
       $decoded_json=json_decode($return);
       $reply["json"]=$decoded_json;
       print_r ( json_encode($reply));
?>
```

My problem is that Json_decode is returning null.

I have checked the encoding(UTF-8), and also checked that the json witch i send to the php file has no slashes or anything.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `print_r(json_encode(...)))` does not return valid json. Just use `print` or `echo` instead of `print_r()`. Because of this you will never enter you `success` function although you could of course check the response in the console.

Comment: replace `print_r ( json_encode($reply));` with `echo json_encode($reply);` This will work as long as $reply is an array.

Comment: no good, the problem still remains

Comment: Can You check the contents of `$_POST["json"]` ?

Comment: try to run the PHP script alone and check for errors.. Something that may throw a notice (or warning) is the fact that $reply isn't declared as an array, hence you should declare it first and then use it as key => value. Also, check if $_POST['json'] is set aswell.

Comment: @user1281678 That's not very helpful. What is the exact response as you can see it in the console?

Comment: if i change the success in javascript to JSOn.strinigy and change the php to the following:  <?php
$return=$_POST["json"];
$decoded_json=json_decode($return);
$reply["json"]=$return;
echo  json_encode($reply);
?> i get this: [{"field":"nome","condition":"=","value":"john"}]

Comment: there are no errors, notices or warnings in php when i run the script standalone

Comment: @user1281678, I'm sorry but I don't understand what is your problem very well... **1-** You make `JSON.stringify(yourJsonObject)` (the PHP `json_decode()` needs a string as a parameter) **2-** Send it with AJAX **3-** Elaborate in PHP **4-** You make `alert(response["json"])`... Please tell me if you have done all the **4** steps (specially the `JSON.stringify()` before to send it with AJAX) Because as it is, it returns `[object Object]` (the JSON object, you can ceck with `alert(JSON.stringify(response["json"]));`) to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ajax data converted to

`[{json : {"field":"name","condition":"<","value":"John"}}]`

It's not valid because of `json :` side.

Convert your Jquery to

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'testPost.php',
    data: {"json": cond},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response["json"]);
    }
});
```

And There is works example here,

```
<?php 
    if(count($_POST) > 0){
        print_r($_POST);
        exit;
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        var cond = [{"field":"name","condition":"<","value":"John"}];
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'a.php',
            data: {"json" : cond},
            dataType: 'text',
            complete: function(response) {
                $("body").html(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Even with that change the json_decode still returns NULL

Comment: i changed 'json' to "json" please try again .

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

You need to add this line in PHP before echo.

Then

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'testPost.php',
    data: {json: cond},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response.field);
        alert(response.condition);
        alert(response.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not needed, he uses `dataType: "json"` ...from [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) *"**dataType** is the type of data that you're expecting **back from the server**. "*

Comment: You should know that not all servers' environment are the same. In some cases, it is needed. You can search this problem on stackoverflow, it is very common issue.

Comment: I fixed the problem but it's a bit silly. At the top of the php I did this:[php]$return=$_POST["json"];
$encode_json=json_encode($return);
$decoded_json=json_decode($encode_json, true );

Answer (score 0):

try using stripslashes() then json_decode()

```
$decoded_json = json_decode(stripslashes($return));
```